# How to get a timestamp string in Tcl script?

Tags: tcl

I dont' know TCL programm language but know python, 
I need to modify a tcl script to get a timestampe string like `050209012020`  (`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`)

Comment: http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to get the time

```
set now [clock seconds]
```

Then do the equivalent of a python f-string

```
set timestr [clock format $now -format "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"]
```

See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl41.html  for further details

Comment: Many thanks Cpu for your quickly help and details sharing! 谢谢!

Comment: Also check out the results of `clock format 1578535500 -format "%M%H%d%m%Y"`

Comment: one line command:  `set date_time_str [clock format [clock seconds] -format "_%y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S"]`

Answer (score 1):

How to convert time stamp to human readable format ? the current output format is timestamp 050209012020 but

> Blockquote

want out put format as date/MM/Year.

```
'#!

proc do_cmd {cmd} {
    puts [exec "$cmd\n" "# " 15]
}
do_cmd "config global"
do_cmd "config system console"
do_cmd "set output standard"
do_cmd "end"
do_cmd "config global"
proc get_sys_status aname {
    upvar $aname a
    set input [exec "get system status | grep Host\n" "# " 15 ]
    set linelist [split $input \n]
    foreach line $linelist {
        if {![regexp {([^:]+):(.*)} $line dummy key value]} continue
            switch -regexp -- $key {
            Hostname {
                set a(hostname) [string trim $value]
            }
        }   
    }
}
get_sys_status status
do_cmd "end"
do_cmd "execute backup $status(hostname)_[clock format [clock seconds] -format %d.%m.%Y].txt'
```

Comment: Please don’t post new questions as answers. Instead, ask a new question. You can reference this thread via your question if that helps offer context.